# iOS NSPredicate to filter Core Data by the parent entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So I am lost on this one. I am trying to fetch objects that are children of a parent object using a predicate. If I take out the predicate line it returns all of the specific posts. So I am pretty sure its an issue with the predicate. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is my setup.

AccountTimeLine -> SpecificPosts (One To Many)

Core Data Model:
[image]

[image]

Fetched Results Controller:

```
- (void)specificPostFetch
{
    DataAccessLayer *delegate = [[DataAccessLayer alloc]init];
    self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
    NSString *entityName = @"SpecificPosts";
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdDateSort" ascending:YES]];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"accountTimeLine = %@", self.accountTimeLineObject];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];
    self.specificPostFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.specificPostFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [self.specificPostFetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
}
```

Print out of the accountTimeLineObject that is used to compare in the predicate

```
po self.accountTimeLineObject
<AccountTimeLine: 0x7c087b70> (entity: AccountTimeLine; id: 0x7c086590 <x-coredata://353F201D-E739-4DD0-BEBF-DAD6101CFE51/AccountTimeLine/p72> ; data: {
    accountType = 0;
    nextPageUrl = 515986477864337411;
    sort = 0;
    specificPosts = "<relationship fault: 0x7c634590 'specificPosts'>";
    userAccountId = 582;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting == in your predicate, not a single =:

```
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"accountTimeLine == %@", self.accountTimeLineObject];
```

Comment: Yea I tried this before. Doesn't change anything. Not sure if there is suppose to be a different between == and = inside these predicates? I have also tried adding ObjectId like this "request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"accountTimeLine == %@", [self.accountTimeLineObject objectID]];" and that didn't work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: Empty Fetched Results Controller when I put a break point on cellForRow. Where as when I comment out the predicate line I get 40 objects back. (lldb) po [self.specificPostFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
<nil>

Comment: And you're sure `self.accountTimeLineObject` is set correctly?

Comment: Pretty sure, the setup I had before I used the accountTimeLineObject directly and had access to the child specific posts. This is what it looks like in the .h file @property (strong, nonatomic) AccountTimeLine *accountTimeLineObject; And in the parent class TwitterFeedViewController *TwitterFeedViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwitterFeedViewController"];
            TwitterFeedViewController.accountTimeLineObject = [self.accountTimeLineFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: How does your DataAccessLayer class get its managedObjectContext?  That's not nil, by any chance, is it?  And does your performFetch return true?  If not, use an error argument to find out what's going wrong.  Sorry if you've already been round that course...

Comment: The managedObjectContext was not nil. The performFetch also returned true. I ended up fetching the "accountTimeLine" instead of the "specificPosts". I then grabbed the NSSet specificPosts off of the accountTimeLine fetchedResultsController. This doesnt seem as efficient, but works.